# Is it possible to add comments to an Overleaf document when sharing using the view-only function?

Tags: overleaf

I want to send my Overleaf document for review to my supervisor.
For this I wish to allow my supervisor to add comments but not to change the code.
Can my supervisor add comments in the view-only sharing more or do I have to give access through the edit mode?

Comment: This site is not Overleaf support. https://www.overleaf.com/contact

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Users who are logged in to Overleaf can make comments even if they only have the read-only link. So all your supervisor needs to make comments is an account.

Comment: @StefanPinnow Why does this not provide an answer to the question? The question asked if it is possible to add comments with read-only share links and this is possible given the conditions listed in my answer .

Comment: Thanks for this answer, @user191173 ! I'm on the support team at Overleaf, I can confirm this is correct. The commenting option won't be shown if the project is accessed anonymously, so the supervisor should make an account. All that's required to make an account is an email address.

Comment: @walszje Thanks for the confirmation!

Comment: (I'm on the support team at Overleaf.) Since my colleague made this comment, we've changed the access permissions for users accessing projects via link sharing. Now it's only possible to comment if you've been invited to a project by email address (with either editing or read-only privileges), or by using a read-and-edit Link Sharing link. [Hi @walszje, hope you're doing well!  ]